# Regex to convert yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: regex

I want to convert this data format

```
20140102
```

to

```
2014-1-2
```

using regex.

the pattern i have tried is as such:

```
([0-9]{4})([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])
```

the problem i have is removing the 0.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Which programming language? Regexes are differently implemented across languages. Also, this problem is solvable without regexes – which, depending on the language, may be a better approach.

Comment: What's your output if the input is `20141112`

Comment: @Chan is this an exact input string?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
(\d{4})(0)?((?(2)\d|\d\d))(0)?((?(4)\d|\d\d))
```

Replace with `\1-\3-\5`.

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/kL1jW1/2)

Explanation:

```
(\d{4}) // capture 4 digits in group 1 (year)
(0)? // next, consume a 0 if possible
( // now, if there was a 0, consume only one more digit
    (?(2)\d
    | // otherwise consume two digits
    \d\d)
) // captured in group 3
(0)? // and the same thing again for the last two digits
(
    (?(4)\d
    |
    \d\d)
)
```

Comment: Note: `(?(n)..)` is not a "common" regular expression construct.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved through use of anchors or word boundaries.

```
^(\d{4})(0)?([1-9])(\d*?)(0)?([1-9]\d?)$
```

OR

```
\b(\d{4})(0)?([1-9])(\d*?)(0)?([1-9]\d?)\b
```

If the input contains only the exact date format  you specified then try the below regex. Lookahead asserts that the input contains exactly 8 characters.

```
^(?=.{8}$)(\d{4})(0)?([1-9])(\d*?)(0)?([1-9]\d?)$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1-$3$4-$6
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jG3iT8/1)

Answer (score 1):

or this pattern

```
(?=(?:\d{4}|\d{2})$)0?
```

and replace w/ `-`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/16)

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it only works if the date is at the end of a line, due to the `$` anchor.

Comment: replace `$` w/ `\b` then :-)

Comment: +1 nice, we aren't sure while the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that this does not necessarily have to be solved with regexes, here's an alternative implementation (in PHP):

```php
$values = [ '20140101', '20141212' ];

foreach ($values as $value)
    var_dump(vsprintf('%d%02d-%d-%d', str_split($value, 2)));
```

Result:

```
string(8) "2014-1-1"
string(10) "2014-12-12"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I *had* to use regular expressions, I would probably do this in two steps (in JavaScript, eg.):

```
"20140102".replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3")
          .replace(/-0/g, "-")
```

In this manner each step can be trivially reasoned about and verified.